# How to write the equation into matrix form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

$[(a+k_i)^2+(b+k_j)^2]X_{i,j}-\sum_{m,n}V_{m,n}X_{i-m,j-n}=\mu X_{i,j}$.
where $-N\le i,j\le N$
 Here we can set $ N=10,a =1, b=1$ and $V_{m,n}$ is the matrix element of $V$. Once I write the coefficient  matrix of $X$, I can solve the eigenvalue $\mu$.

Comment: A matrix is a list of lists.  For example if $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$, we would write this in *Mathematica* as `A={{1,2},{3,4}}`.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: What are the bounds of the summation `\sum_{m,n}`?

Answer (score 2):

$X$ is a $N\times N$ matrix, which I'll `Flatten` into a vector of length $N^2$. The coefficient array is a $N\times N\times N\times N$ tensor, which I'll `ArrayFlatten` into a $N^2\times N^2$ matrix.

I'll use `M`=$N$ because the symbol `N` is already in use in *Mathematica*. The coefficient array is `W`. Here I'll use `M=3` for brevity.

```
M = 3;
X = Flatten[Array[Subscript[x, ##] &, {M, M}]];
W = ArrayFlatten[SparseArray[{i_,i_,j_,j_} ->
                   (a+Subscript[k,i])^2 + (b+Subscript[k,j])^2, {M,M,M,M}] - 
                 SparseArray[{i1_,i2_,j1_,j2_} ->
                   Subscript[V,i1-i2,j1-j2], {M,M,M,M}]];
```

Note that the second component of `W` is not sparse, and can be written as

```
Array[Subscript[V, #1-#2, #3-#4] &, {M, M, M, M}]
```

which may be more efficient, but harder on the eye.

Check that this gives the desired eigenvalue equations:

```
Thread[W.X == μ X]
```

$$
\{((a+k_1){}^2+(b+k_1){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{1,1}-V_{0,-1} x_{1,2}-V_{0,-2} x_{1,3}-V_{-1,0} x_{2,1}-V_{-1,-1} x_{2,2}-V_{-1,-2}
   x_{2,3}-V_{-2,0} x_{3,1}-V_{-2,-1} x_{3,2}-V_{-2,-2} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{1,1},\\
-V_{0,1}
   x_{1,1}+((a+k_1){}^2+(b+k_2){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{1,2}-V_{0,-1} x_{1,3}-V_{-1,1} x_{2,1}-V_{-1,0} x_{2,2}-V_{-1,-1} x_{2,3}-V_{-2,1}
   x_{3,1}-V_{-2,0} x_{3,2}-V_{-2,-1} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{1,2},\\
-V_{0,2} x_{1,1}-V_{0,1}
   x_{1,2}+((a+k_1){}^2+(b+k_3){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{1,3}-V_{-1,2} x_{2,1}-V_{-1,1} x_{2,2}-V_{-1,0} x_{2,3}-V_{-2,2} x_{3,1}-V_{-2,1}
   x_{3,2}-V_{-2,0} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{1,3},\\
-V_{1,0} x_{1,1}-V_{1,-1} x_{1,2}-V_{1,-2}
   x_{1,3}+((b+k_1){}^2+(a+k_2){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{2,1}-V_{0,-1} x_{2,2}-V_{0,-2} x_{2,3}-V_{-1,0} x_{3,1}-V_{-1,-1} x_{3,2}-V_{-1,-2}
   x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{2,1},\\
-V_{1,1} x_{1,1}-V_{1,0} x_{1,2}-V_{1,-1} x_{1,3}-V_{0,1}
   x_{2,1}+((a+k_2){}^2+(b+k_2){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{2,2}-V_{0,-1} x_{2,3}-V_{-1,1} x_{3,1}-V_{-1,0} x_{3,2}-V_{-1,-1} x_{3,3}=\mu 
   x_{2,2},\\
-V_{1,2} x_{1,1}-V_{1,1} x_{1,2}-V_{1,0} x_{1,3}-V_{0,2} x_{2,1}-V_{0,1}
   x_{2,2}+((a+k_2){}^2+(b+k_3){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{2,3}-V_{-1,2} x_{3,1}-V_{-1,1} x_{3,2}-V_{-1,0} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{2,3},\\
-V_{2,0}
   x_{1,1}-V_{2,-1} x_{1,2}-V_{2,-2} x_{1,3}-V_{1,0} x_{2,1}-V_{1,-1} x_{2,2}-V_{1,-2}
   x_{2,3}+((b+k_1){}^2+(a+k_3){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{3,1}-V_{0,-1} x_{3,2}-V_{0,-2} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{3,1},\\
-V_{2,1} x_{1,1}-V_{2,0}
   x_{1,2}-V_{2,-1} x_{1,3}-V_{1,1} x_{2,1}-V_{1,0} x_{2,2}-V_{1,-1} x_{2,3}-V_{0,1}
   x_{3,1}+((b+k_2){}^2+(a+k_3){}^2-V_{0,0})
   x_{3,2}-V_{0,-1} x_{3,3}=\mu  x_{3,2},\\
-V_{2,2} x_{1,1}-V_{2,1} x_{1,2}-V_{2,0}
   x_{1,3}-V_{1,2} x_{2,1}-V_{1,1} x_{2,2}-V_{1,0} x_{2,3}-V_{0,2} x_{3,1}-V_{0,1}
   x_{3,2}+((a+k_3){}^2+(b+k_3){}^2-V_{0,0}) x_{3,3}=\mu
x_{3,3}\}
$$

Find the eigenvalues:

```
Eigenvalues[W]
```

You'll probably have to insert numerical values into `W` before calculating the eigenvalues, otherwise the code will be too slow.

Comment: It is a little perverse to use `SparseArray[]` to generate what is actually a dense matrix. In any event: `ArrayFlatten[Table[If[i1 == i2 && j1 == j2, ((a + Subscript[k, i1])^2 + (b + Subscript[k, j1])^2), 0] - Subscript[V, i1 - i2, j1 - j2], {i1, M}, {i2, M}, {j1, M}, {j2, M}]]`

Comment: Yes I just commented on that. I tend to prefer `SparseArray` because it's easy to debug, and once it works I try to find more efficient forms.

Comment: thank， I  will  understand  it  now

Comment: This code looks perfect, but  it may be a little abstract.  Maybe I can't understand and imagine the mathematical form.  Because for one subscript, I can write the matrix by hand and to observe the form.  But for two subscript, the matrix is very large even for $N=3$, the matrix is $9\times 9$.  My question is : Can you give me some detailed examples which involved the later case.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "detailed examples", other than the 9 equations I already gave explicitly for the case `M=3`. Can you please formulate your question more concretely?

Comment: Can  you  suggest me  some  book  which  introduce systemically how to   write  differential  equation  into  matrix  form especially for 2 dimension case? thanks .

Comment: Have a look at chapter 4 of my book: https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050